# Can a Swedish citizen on government benefits invite a person to stay with them?

Tags: visas, sweden, invitation-letters

I'm a Swedish citizen living in a flat rent is paid by the Swedish Social Security system. I want to invite my friend, an Indian, to visit me. Will it be a problem for Social Security if I invite my friend? He will just stay at my place. All the expenses are borne by him. He works in India. He will show his income. I'm wondering if I provide the invitation to him, the Social Security office might ask me questions.

By *on social,* I mean that I'm not working, unemployed, and government is giving me money every month.

Comment: If your friend is paying all expenses anyway, things will be easier if he just budgets for staying at a hotel. Visa applications that need to rely on a local resident providing accommodations are _weaker_ than when the applicant can fund the entire trip alone.

Comment: The social security officer will not care at all. You can even have visitors from Sweden over! Just don't put *too much* of his money on your bank accounts.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.  The onus is on him, as the visitor, to show he has funds to support himself.

So - he'll have to show proof of the invite - that's fine, you're able to help with that.

Then he'll have to show funds. If he's staying at yours, then at least he won't need as much as won't have to pay for accommodation.  But as long as he satisfies immigration that he has enough funds to support himself, and meets all other criteria, he should be allowed in.

IF they do ask *you* questions - just be honest. You're offering a roof over his head, and he's paying for his own expenses, so it's not affecting your income/expenses, as he's supporting himself. Then it's on him to provide the proof, which, reasonably - if he can't do, shouldn't be coming.